# How to create fading drop shadow effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Any advice on how to create the shadow effect in the attached image would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd simply use a Gradient Mesh, set to multiply. And set all the mesh points to 0% opacity except a center point used to generate the shadow.

[image: Gradient Mesh Shadow]

Answer (score 2):

Another flexible way is given in the Julian's answer to [How to “draw” pointed corner drop shadows in Adobe Illustrator CS5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9153/10206). You can control the shape of shadow by controlling the shape who drops the shadow (see the demo. below).

To your requirement, just pull the bottom-center anchor down to make it a little bit convex.
I find it a really flexible method of making different drop shadows.

[image: shadows demo]

Answer (score 1):

Another, bit more flexible way would be to use the Appearance palette.

- Add a new fill to your shape, drag it behind the original shape, and
  make it black.
- Then use Effect > Convert to Shape > Ellipse... on the black fill,
  changing it into a really thin, but very broad ellipse that fits
  behind the original fill. Reducing the original fill's opacity helps
  here.
- After that, Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform... and play with
  Vertical Move until the ellipse is partly visible on the lower rim of
  your fill.
- Finally, Effect > Blur > Gaussian Blur the black fill and reduce its
  opacity as you see fit.

(CS3 terms and menus used)

Comment: Definitely a viable solution. I find, for me, raster effects such as Gaussian Blur are not always a great solution when comparing them to actual editable vectors such as the Gradient mesh.

Comment: to each their own. I find the gradient mesh a clunky tool, but that's probably because I'm using CS3.