# What is the name of this type of shadow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Photoshop curved Shadow](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/photoshop-curved-shadow)

I've seen these a lot recently and I want to learn how to create them in Photoshop!
Here's the image I'm talking about:

[image: shadow]

Comment: yep, it's a dupe, sorry. The answer on that question is really cool, thanks!

Comment: There's also a question about how to do that exact pointed corner style drop shadow in Illustrator http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9151/how-to-draw-pointed-corner-drop-shadows-in-adobe-illustrator-cs5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop shadow. more advanced than the average one but still a drop shadow..

Comment: apparently it's just a drop shaddow with a gradient mask http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/photoshop-curved-shadow

Comment: a very cool tutorial on warped masks can be found here http://onwired.com/blog/better-drop-shadows/