# Perfect orthographic projection/ using perspective filters in photoshop/illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, perspective, drop-shadow

I wan to get a perfect orthographic projection as seen here:
[image]

I have tried to use the perspective warp on a page I made myself and achieved the following effect:
[image]

As you can see I seem to achieve more distortion and rather than the illusion. Can someone tell me how to use the perspective filters in photoshop to achieve the required result while maintaining the proportions like in the first image. 
Now I know that illustrator can be used to create orthographic guides but the problem there is the drop shadow. Its too confusing and I tried but simply could'nt get the values right. If someone can guide me to use drop shadow in illustrator that would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the perspective, just take your art, rotate it 45deg counter-clockwise, then scale it 50% vertically.

Then do the shadow. I can't see enough of it to guess at the values, but the Drop Shadow effect should do the trick there.

Answer (score 1):

Try not using a filter, go for a custom built shadow by adding a dark color shape to the underside of your lit subject then use a blur filter, copy shape dimensions and paste to layer below, then tweak the edges back under the top layer so exposing a smaller part of the shadow layer. a more natural look you might cause two of these shadows (2 light sources) maybe in slightly different colours

Comment: Nice little demo for one solution here http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/how-to-create-fading-drop-shadow-effect-in-illustrator

Comment: That takes care of the shadow. What about the perspective?